# Partial Restore

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to restore from a full backup or parrallel db, only certain records with original IDs?

Lets say records were deleted from a specific date, can those records be restored without restoring the entire table?

So to be clear lets say I have records 500 - 720 still in a backup or parrallel db, but the table has had new records added since the backup so dont want to lose them either. So simply want to slot records 500 - 720 back with their original IDs to the current table.

Comment: Can you please describe/post up some examples of linked records that have been deleted, and their relationship to the main set of data you are trying to restore?

Comment: lets say table1 has a field called ID (int PK) and table2 has a field called ID (int PK) and field table1ID (int), hope this helps.

Comment: glad you got it sorted - a click on the tick would go down nicely please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a copy of the db, that's going to be the easiest and quickest way - create a copy of your table with just the rows you need:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
AS
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE  table1.ID BETWEEN 500 AND 720
```

then dump table2 with mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -u -p thedatabase table2 > table2_dump.sql
```

and ship the dump to the main db, run the dump when using a temporary database, and insert the missing records using:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT *
FROM   temp_db.table2
```

If you don't have a copy of the db with the missing records, just a backup, then I don't think you can do such a selective restore. If you just have a single dump file of the entire db, then you will have to restore a complete copy to a temporary db, and insert the missing records in a similar manner to the way I've described above, but with a where clause in the insert.

Comment: Thank you that worked a treat, but I have another issue. They're is a related table which has had linked ID records removed. I've tried the same process on the temp db but I am getting duplicate entry warnings for the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I've figured out the last part, simply ran the following against the full backed up table:

INSERT IGNORE INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM backedup_table

Then I ran the following to cleanup:

DELETE table2
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID = table2.table1ID);

Got there in the end, thank you for your assistance :-)